# Excel formula to use numbers and first space as delimiter

Tags: excel, crystal-reports-xi

I have written a Crystal Report for a user who exports the report as a "Microsoft Excel (97-2003) Data-Only" file. One of the columns is an address that is in the following format:

123 Main Street

456 S 3rd St

789 N W Lane

There are always a series of numbers followed by a single space and then the rest of the address. Is there an Excel formula that I can write against this column that would remove the first numbers and the first space - so that I can end up with the following, in this case:

Main Street

S 3rd St

N W Lane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably more than a handful of ways to do what you want.  One way would be to find the location of the first space, then take all of the characters to the right of it.  For instance:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))
```

Worked on your sample data.  Depending on the quality of your data, this may be quite brittle and you should wrap it in error checking formulas as appropriate.

Comment: I just realized that I am actually not sure how to apply this to a cell or to a column.

Comment: well let's assume your data starts in A1.  You'd copy this formula in to B1 and drag it down.  Without knowing the layout of your sheet, I dont' know if I can help you any more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your string is in A2 then try this

```
=REPLACE(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2),"")
```